# How to convert a list to numeric string ranges in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, sorting

How would I convert a list such as:

```
list = ['X70', 'X71', 'X72', 'X73', 'X75', 'X76', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80']
```

into a string like this:

```
string = "X70 - X73, X75 - X77, X79, X80".
```

I found how to do the other way around without letters.

Comment: Why not `X79 - X80` for the last two?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to join the numbers based on the letters and consecutive numbers with a threshold of a minimum consecutive numbers:

```
import re
def compress(lst, thresh=2):
    out = []
    tmp = []
    prev = (None, float('nan'))
    for s in lst+['0']:
        letter, num = re.search(r'(\D*)(\d+)', s).groups()
        num = int(num)
        if letter == prev[0] and num == prev[1]+1:
            tmp.append(s)
        else:
            if len(tmp) <= thresh:
                out.extend(tmp)
            else:
                out.append(tmp[0]+f"-{prev[1]}")
            tmp = [s]
        prev = (letter, num)
    return ', '.join(out)
```

Examples:

```
lst = ['X1', 'X2', 'X70', 'X71', 'X72', 'X73', 'X75', 'X76', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80', 'X85']
   
compress(lst, thresh=1)
# X1-2, X70-73, X75-77, X79-80, X85

compress(lst, thresh=2)
# X1, X2, X70-73, X75-77, X79, X80, X85

compress(lst, thresh=3)
# X1, X2, X70-73, X75, X76, X77, X79, X80, X85

compress([])
# 

compress(['X1'])
# X1

compress(['X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'Y4', 'X5'])
# X1-3, Y4, X5
```

Answer (score 1):

- Convert to list of ints
- Optionally, sort the list
- Convert to list of intervals
- Convert back to string using `', '.join(...)` and `' - '.join(...)`

```py
# convert to list of intervals
def compress(seq):
    it = iter(l_int)
    x = next(it)
    a,b = x,x    # initialise current interval
    for x in it:
        if x == b+1:  # extend current interval
            b = x
        else:         # start new interval
            yield ((a,b) if b != a else a)
            a,b = x,x
    yield ((a,b) if b != a else a)

# print(list(compress([70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80])))
# [(70, 73), (75, 77), (79, 80)]

# convert back to string
def stringify(compressed_seq):
    return ', '.join(' - '.join(f'X{bound}' for bound in interval)
                     for interval in compressed_seq)

# print(stringify([(70, 73), (75, 77), (79, 80)]))
# X70 - X73, X75 - X77, X79 - X80

def listofstrings_to_numericstringranges(seq):
    seq = (int(s[1:]) for s in l_str)   # convert to list of integers
    seq = sorted(seq)                   # optional step
    seq = compress(seq)                 # convert to list of intervals
    return stringify(seq)               # convert back to string

print(
    listofstrings_to_numericstringranges(['X70', 'X71', 'X72', 'X73', 'X75', 'X76', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80'])
)
# 'X70 - X73, X75 - X77, X79 - X80'
```

If you like module `more_itertools`, here is a different version of function `compress` using [`more_itertools.split_when`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_when):

```py
from more_itertools import split_when

def compress(seq):
    return (((g[0],g[-1]) if len(g) >= 2 else g[0])
            for g in split_when(seq, lambda x,y: y > x+1))

# print(list(compress([70, 71, 72, 73, 75, 76, 77, 79, 80])))
# [(70, 73), (75, 77), (79, 80)]
```

Comment: I like the `more_itertools` approach (but be careful if g[0] == g[-1]) ;)

Comment: @mozway Oops, yes, this should be fixed now, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with after some playing around. I would be surprised if there isn't a better way to do this, but it works.

As an aside, I renamed `list` to `xlist` since the name `list` shadows a reserved keyword in Python.

```
xlist = ['X70', 'X71', 'X72', 'X73', 'X75', 'X76', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80']
intermediate = []  # empty placeholder list
result = ''  # string to store the final result

# create an intermediate list, skipping 'inside' consecutive values
intermediate = [  # 'int(item[-2:])' is getting the numeric value of the item
    item for item in xlist if 
    f'X{int(item[-2:]) - 1}' not in xlist or 
    f'X{int(item[-2:]) + 1}' not in xlist
]
# => ['X70', 'X73', 'X75', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80']

# create the result string from the contents of the intermediate list
for index, item in enumerate(intermediate):
    try:
        # if there are consecutive entries, join them with ' - '
        if int(intermediate[index + 1][-2:]) > int(item[-2:]) + 1:
            result += f'{item} - {intermediate[index + 1]}, '
            intermediate.pop(index)
        else:  # otherwise, just add them to the result string
            result += f'{item}, '
    except IndexError:  # last item, just add it to the string
        result += item


print(result)
# => X70 - X73, X75 - X77, X79, X80
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work on `xlist = ['X1', 'X70', 'X71', 'X72', 'X73', 'X75', 'X76', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80', 'X85']`

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `yield` (slightly different than Stef did) is:

```
import re

my_list = ['X70', 'X71', 'X72', 'X73', 'X75', 'X76', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80']

def my_group(my_list):
    tmp = [int(re.findall(r'(\d+$)', x)[0]) for x in my_list]
    res = [my_list[0]]
    for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
        if tmp[i] + 1 == tmp[i + 1]:
            res.append(my_list[i + 1])
        else:
            yield str(res[0]) + '-' + str(res[-1])
            res = [my_list[i + 1]]
    yield str(res[0]) + '-' + str(res[-1])
  
print(list(my_group(my_list)))
#['X70-X73', 'X75-X77', 'X79-X80']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your items are sorted in alpha and numerical order, you could use groupy (from itertools) to organize consecutive values in groups and then format the srtings with separators based on the size of each group:

```
from itertools import groupby

L = ['X70', 'X71', 'X72', 'X73', 'X75', 'X76', 'X77', 'X79', 'X80']

G = ( (S[:1],int(S[1:])-i) for i,S in enumerate(L) )

R = ", ".join(i0 + ["",", "+g[-1]," - "+g[-1]][len(g[:2])]
              for _,(i0,*g) in groupby(L,key=lambda _:next(G)) )


print(R)
X70 - X73, X75 - X77, X79, X80
```